# Why my react front end does not want to download my file sent from my express back end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

hope you can help me on this one!
Here is the situation: I want to download a file from my React front end by sending a request to a certain endpoint on my express back end.
Here is my controller for this route.
I build a query, parse the results to generate a csv file and send back that file.
When I console log the response on the front end side, the data is there, it goes through; however, no dialog open allowing the client to download the file on local disk.

```
module.exports.downloadFile = async (req, res) => {
    const sql = await buildQuery(req.query, 'members', connection)
    // Select the wanted data from the database
    connection.query(sql, (err, results, fields) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Convert the json into csv
        try{
            const csv = parse(results);
            // Save the file on server
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/export.csv', csv)
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=export.csv');
            res.download(__dirname + '/export.csv');
        } catch (err){
            console.error(err)
        }

        // Reply with the csv file
        // Delete the file
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow one of these functions as an example to your client side code:

Async:

```
export const download = (url, filename) => {
    fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors' 
        /*
        * ALTERNATIVE MODE {
        mode: 'cors'
        }
        *
        */
    }).then((transfer) => {
        return transfer.blob();                // RETURN DATA TRANSFERED AS BLOB
    }).then((bytes) => {
        let elm = document.createElement('a');  // CREATE A LINK ELEMENT IN DOM
        elm.href = URL.createObjectURL(bytes);  // SET LINK ELEMENTS CONTENTS
        elm.setAttribute('download', filename); // SET ELEMENT CREATED 'ATTRIBUTE' TO DOWNLOAD, FILENAME PARAM AUTOMATICALLY
        elm.click();                             // TRIGGER ELEMENT TO DOWNLOAD
        elm.remove();
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);                     // OUTPUT ERRORS, SUCH AS CORS WHEN TESTING NON LOCALLY
    })
}
```

Sync:

```
export const download = async (url, filename) => {
    let response = await fetch(url, {
        mode: 'no-cors' 
        /*
        * ALTERNATIVE MODE {
        mode: 'cors'
        }
        *
        */  
    }); 
    try {
        let data = await response.blob();
        let elm = document.createElement('a');  // CREATE A LINK ELEMENT IN DOM
        elm.href = URL.createObjectURL(data);  // SET LINK ELEMENTS CONTENTS
        elm.setAttribute('download', filename); // SET ELEMENT CREATED 'ATTRIBUTE' TO DOWNLOAD, FILENAME PARAM AUTOMATICALLY
        elm.click();                             // TRIGGER ELEMENT TO DOWNLOAD
        elm.remove();
    } 
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }   
}
```